# whitespace issue on glyphicon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am struggling to figure out how to remove the white space in the glyphicon.

Ideally if i could get the `display:inline-block` go to away my life would be so much happier.

Can anyone suggest some options ? I am pretty much out of options at this point. :(

below is a working sample of my issue

https://stevia-affirm.codio.io/VerticalBootstrapTable.html

```
 <!--
To change this template use Tools | Templates.
-->
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
      <title>Bootstrap Vertical Table</title>
    <!-- for css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- for JavaScript  -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- for Fonts  -->
    <link href="css/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style>
        #no-more-tables .glyphicon {display:block;text-align:center;height:auto;top:-1px !important;}
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

    /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
    #no-more-tables table, 
    #no-more-tables thead, 
    #no-more-tables tbody, 
    #no-more-tables th, 
    #no-more-tables td, 
    #no-more-tables tr { 
        display: block; 
    }

    /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
    #no-more-tables thead tr { 
        position: absolute;
        top: -9999px;
        left: -9999px;
    }

    #no-more-tables tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

    #no-more-tables td { 
        /* Behave  like a "row" */
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; 
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 50%; 
        white-space: normal;
        text-align:left;
    }

    #no-more-tables td:before { 
        /* Now like a table header */
        position: absolute;
        /* Top/left values mimic padding */
        top: 6px;
        left: 6px;
        width: 45%; 
        padding-right: 10px; 
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-align:left;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    /*
    Label the data
    */
    #no-more-tables td:before { content: attr(data-title); }
}</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <!-- <div class="row"> -->
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1 class="text-center">
                No more tables.
            </h1>

        </div>
        <div id="no-more-tables">
            <table class="col-md-12 table-bordered table-striped table-condensed cf table-hover">
                <thead class="cf">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Pencil</th>
                        <th>Code</th>
                        <th>Company</th>
                        <th class="numeric">Price</th>
                        <th class="numeric">Change</th>
                        <th class="numeric">Change %</th>
                        <th class="numeric">Open</th>
                        <th class="numeric">High</th>
                        <th class="numeric">Low</th>
                        <th class="numeric">Volume</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="top: 0px;"></td>
                        <td data-title="Code">AAC</td>
                        <td data-title="Company">AUSTRALIAN AGRICULTURAL COMPANY LIMITED.</td>
                        <td data-title="Price" class="numeric">$1.38</td>
                        <td data-title="Change" class="numeric">-0.01</td>
                        <td data-title="Change %" class="numeric">-0.36%</td>
                        <td data-title="Open" class="numeric">$1.39</td>
                        <td data-title="High" class="numeric">$1.39</td>
                        <td data-title="Low" class="numeric">$1.38</td>
                        <td data-title="Volume" class="numeric">9,395</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                          <td class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="top: 0px;"></td>
                        <td data-title="Code">AAD</td>
                        <td data-title="Company">ARDENT LEISURE GROUP</td>
                        <td data-title="Price" class="numeric">$1.15</td>
                        <td data-title="Change" class="numeric">+0.02</td>
                        <td data-title="Change %" class="numeric">1.32%</td>
                        <td data-title="Open" class="numeric">$1.14</td>
                        <td data-title="High" class="numeric">$1.15</td>
                        <td data-title="Low" class="numeric">$1.13</td>
                        <td data-title="Volume" class="numeric">56,431</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                          <td class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="top: 0px;"></td>
                        <td data-title="Code">AAX</td>
                        <td data-title="Company">AUSENCO LIMITED</td>
                        <td data-title="Price" class="numeric">$4.00</td>
                        <td data-title="Change" class="numeric">-0.04</td>
                        <td data-title="Change %" class="numeric">-0.99%</td>
                        <td data-title="Open" class="numeric">$4.01</td>
                        <td data-title="High" class="numeric">$4.05</td>
                        <td data-title="Low" class="numeric">$4.00</td>
                        <td data-title="Volume" class="numeric">90,641</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                          <td class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="top: 0px;"></td>
                        <td data-title="Code">ABC</td>
                        <td data-title="Company">ADELAIDE BRIGHTON LIMITED</td>
                        <td data-title="Price" class="numeric">$3.00</td>
                        <td data-title="Change" class="numeric">+0.06</td>
                        <td data-title="Change %" class="numeric">2.04%</td>
                        <td data-title="Open" class="numeric">$2.98</td>
                        <td data-title="High" class="numeric">$3.00</td>
                        <td data-title="Low" class="numeric">$2.96</td>
                        <td data-title="Volume" class="numeric">862,518</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                          <td class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="top: 0px;"></td>
                        <td data-title="Code">ABP</td>
                        <td data-title="Company">ABACUS PROPERTY GROUP</td>
                        <td data-title="Price" class="numeric">$1.91</td>
                        <td data-title="Change" class="numeric">0.00</td>
                        <td data-title="Change %" class="numeric">0.00%</td>
                        <td data-title="Open" class="numeric">$1.92</td>
                        <td data-title="High" class="numeric">$1.93</td>
                        <td data-title="Low" class="numeric">$1.90</td>
                        <td data-title="Volume" class="numeric">595,701</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                          <td class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="top: 0px;"></td>
                        <td data-title="Code">ABY</td>
                        <td data-title="Company">ADITYA BIRLA MINERALS LIMITED</td>
                        <td data-title="Price" class="numeric">$0.77</td>
                        <td data-title="Change" class="numeric">+0.02</td>
                        <td data-title="Change %" class="numeric">2.00%</td>
                        <td data-title="Open" class="numeric">$0.76</td>
                        <td data-title="High" class="numeric">$0.77</td>
                        <td data-title="Low" class="numeric">$0.76</td>
                        <td data-title="Volume" class="numeric">54,567</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                          <td class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="top: 0px;"></td>
                        <td data-title="Code">ACR</td>
                        <td data-title="Company">ACRUX LIMITED</td>
                        <td data-title="Price" class="numeric">$3.71</td>
                        <td data-title="Change" class="numeric">+0.01</td>
                        <td data-title="Change %" class="numeric">0.14%</td>
                        <td data-title="Open" class="numeric">$3.70</td>
                        <td data-title="High" class="numeric">$3.72</td>
                        <td data-title="Low" class="numeric">$3.68</td>
                        <td data-title="Volume" class="numeric">191,373</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                          <td class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="top: 0px;"></td>
                        <td data-title="Code">ADU</td>
                        <td data-title="Company">ADAMUS RESOURCES LIMITED</td>
                        <td data-title="Price" class="numeric">$0.72</td>
                        <td data-title="Change" class="numeric">0.00</td>
                        <td data-title="Change %" class="numeric">0.00%</td>
                        <td data-title="Open" class="numeric">$0.73</td>
                        <td data-title="High" class="numeric">$0.74</td>
                        <td data-title="Low" class="numeric">$0.72</td>
                        <td data-title="Volume" class="numeric">8,602,291</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                          <td class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="top: 0px;"></td>
                        <td data-title="Code">AGG</td>
                        <td data-title="Company">ANGLOGOLD ASHANTI LIMITED</td>
                        <td data-title="Price" class="numeric">$7.81</td>
                        <td data-title="Change" class="numeric">-0.22</td>
                        <td data-title="Change %" class="numeric">-2.74%</td>
                        <td data-title="Open" class="numeric">$7.82</td>
                        <td data-title="High" class="numeric">$7.82</td>
                        <td data-title="Low" class="numeric">$7.81</td>
                        <td data-title="Volume" class="numeric">148</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                          <td class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="top: 0px;"></td>
                        <td data-title="Code">AGK</td>
                        <td data-title="Company">AGL ENERGY LIMITED</td>
                        <td data-title="Price" class="numeric">$13.82</td>
                        <td data-title="Change" class="numeric">+0.02</td>
                        <td data-title="Change %" class="numeric">0.14%</td>
                        <td data-title="Open" class="numeric">$13.83</td>
                        <td data-title="High" class="numeric">$13.83</td>
                        <td data-title="Low" class="numeric">$13.67</td>
                        <td data-title="Volume" class="numeric">846,403</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                          <td class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="top: 0px;"></td>
                        <td data-title="Code">AGO</td>
                        <td data-title="Company">ATLAS IRON LIMITED</td>
                        <td data-title="Price" class="numeric">$3.17</td>
                        <td data-title="Change" class="numeric">-0.02</td>
                        <td data-title="Change %" class="numeric">-0.47%</td>
                        <td data-title="Open" class="numeric">$3.11</td>
                        <td data-title="High" class="numeric">$3.22</td>
                        <td data-title="Low" class="numeric">$3.10</td>
                        <td data-title="Volume" class="numeric">5,416,303</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p class="bg-success" style="padding:10px;margin-top:20px"><small><a href="http://elvery.net/demo/responsive-tables/#no-more-tables" target="_blank">Link</a> to original article</small></p>
    </div>
<!-- </div> -->`enter code here`
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what white space to you mean, do you want it centered in teh table-cell?

Comment: Please paste the relevant parts of your code into the body of your question. Without it, it takes answerers more effort to diagnose your problem and makes this question potentially useless to future visitors, as live resources (like the page you've linked) are extremely susceptible to going dead.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/budag/1/edit -- my answer has this, but I would put it inside the td

Comment: Your first problem is having the `td` be the glyphicon element.  You should have the glyphicon inside the `td`: `<td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></td>`.  That's the recommended way of putting glyphicons in your HTML: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-how-to-use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#no-more-tables .glyphicon {display:block;text-align:center;height:auto;}
```

This will make it block.

http://jsbin.com/budag/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Put the glyphicon inside the table-cell:

```
<td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></td>
```

If you dont want it as a inline block, just change it to a block

```
.glyphicon.glyphicon-pencil  {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: The reason I put the class on the <td> is because I have an angular click event that cause the pencil to not be clickable if I use a span as suggested.  :(